# Google Spreedsheet calculate iside an IF statement

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

### Google spreadsheets help

**Hi there!** im new to google spredsheet and i really want to learn it, can someone explain to me why this wont work

```
IF(F2>E2*100, "yes","no")
```

. Im used to coding and so on but ii can't figure this one out!

What im trying to achive here is to check **if The value inside F2** is bigger than the value inside **E2*100**. After that i vould like **G2 to say either Yes or No**.

I hope you undertsnad my question

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please follow the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works. You just forgot to use "=" in front of the formula:

```
=IF(VALUE(F2)>VALUE(E2)*102;"yes";"no")
```

There is nothing wrong with that:

[image: Illustration]

Comment: I get this error "errors in formula interpretation" THat is the only thing given to me

Comment: It worked very well, guess i was a bit tired yesterday. I appreciate your help alot! Is there someway that i can make that IF statement to work in the entire G column without entering the statement in every little "box" and changing the E and F values from 2 to 3 and so on? I tried "F2:100 and E2:100" But did not work very well.

Comment: @officialrized please ask this in a separate question. It should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(F2>E2*100; "yes"; "no")
```